# pass value from controller to another controller on another page - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am trying to pass a value from one controller to other controller. Both controllers are on same module. I tried by creating service. The issue is I am able to pass value to service from 1st controller, but not able to retrieve that value on 2nd controller. Any help would be appreciated.  is given on items page.

**Controller 1** **(which is on items page)**:

```
itpApp.controller("itpAppControllerKB", function($scope, sharedProperties, $location) { 
$scope.showArticles = function(myValue) {

         console.log('myValue: ' + myValue);

         sharedProperties.setListName(myValue);

         window.location.href = "/portal/articles";
    };

});
```

**Controller 2 (which is on articles page)**:

```
itpApp.controller("itpAppControllerKBArticle", function($scope, sharedProperties) {
$scope.article = sharedProperties.getListName();

console.log('selTopic: ' + $scope.article);
}
```

**Service**:

```
itpApp.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var list_name = '';
    return {

        getListName: function() {
            return list_name;
        },
        setListName: function(name) {
            list_name = name;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Why have you a return state on service ? Factory need it but not service. That's your mistake

Comment: Does window.location.href = "/portal/articles"; forces to reload your page? In case all your service data is lost...

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/VEgt5v9VmeRPU4QIYArF?p=preview  . If I use the service from this link. Its working, but I am getting all the previous values too.

Comment: Use this.getListName = function(){...}. Not return to make a singleton. See docs here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_services.htm

Comment: Then how to avoid reload page - @fubbe.

Comment: If the location.href actually forces the page to reload as mentioned, try to use the $location from angular itself to redirect https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099969/angularjs-pass-value-from-one-page-to-another. I tried this but still same result.

Comment: Sorry, I removed my answer to quickly @fubbe.

Comment: In your path, this is not a service but a factory so there is a return statement. @user3781360

Answer (score 0):

Don't use return statement on your service. Here is an example:

```
itpApp.service('sharedProperties', function () {
  this.list_name = '';

  this.getListName = function() {
      return this.list_name;
  };

  this.setListName = function(name) {
      this.list_name = name;
  };
});
```

Comment: @op use this and location, you should be fine.